# I am a Photoshop scripting beginner. I want to ask everyone how to replace the text layer

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop-script

I am a Photoshop scripting beginner. I want to ask everyone how to replace the text layer in photoshop with Photoshop to read the contents of the external txt file. I am very annoyed.

Answer (score 0):

First load the contents of the external text-file:

```
var extText = new File("path/to/external.txt");
if( extText ) {
    extText.open('r');
    var content = "";
    while(!extText.eof) contents += extText.readln() + "\n";
    extText.close();
};
```

Then use that the contents to update your text-layer:

```
var textLayer = app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("layer-name");  

textLayer.textItem.contents = contents;
```

Hope this will help you feel less annoyed ;)

Comment: Not available，sir

Comment: What is the error? Do you have a text-layer called "layer-name"?

Comment: Ah, I see. The `open()` command might not return the file. I have updated the answer. If you still have trouble use this line: `var extText = new File(File.openDialog())`

Comment: Why does the replacement text layer appear "undefined"?

Comment: What is the error? Do you have a text-layer called `layer-name`?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know why.

Comment: I understand English is not your strongest skill. What is the error message?